# How to publish asp.net mvc 4 project with existing sql database to windows azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-storage

I have a mvc 4 project that uses sql database which is already populated with data. I found   [this tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/) on how to create new sql database in windows azure but can I use my database that already exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search: [SQL Database Migration Wizard (SQLAzureMW) is designed to help you migrate your SQL Server 2005/2008/2012 databases to Azure SQL Database.](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have an [SQL 2005 to SQL Azure Migration blog post](http://berniecook.wordpress.com/2012/05/28/sql-2005-to-sql-azure-migration/) which describes how to achieve this using the [SQL Database Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/).

It's not using ASP.NET MVC or SQL 2008 R2 per se but it will still work if your sole intent is to get a local database into SQL Azure.

Comment: I recently migrated a database to Azure and just went to SQL Server, right click, Deploy Database to Azure and the Management Studio helped me along the way. Is there any advantage on using the Migration Wizard vs. the one that already comes with the latest version of the Management Studio Tools?

Comment: I haven't used the SQL Server feature to deploy a database to SQL Azure but I'm guessing SQL Server does a lot of the heavy lifting that the Migration Wizard doesn't. I imagine both copies would be the same (given the effort invested in both, and the regular updates available) but if you wanted to compare them to be 100% sure you could use Red Gates "SQL Compare 10" tool.